# Is there any way to check how many read/write on Cloud Firestore via sdk?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to check how many read/write on my app on Cloud Firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is no API to get the number of reads/writes from Cloud Firestore. Neither the client-side SDKs nor the server-side Admin SDKs expose this functionality.

The closest I can think of is something based on [StackDriver monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/monitor-usage#stackdriver-monitoring) that you can set up for Firestore. Based on that you can then wrap the [StackDriver monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/) in a custom end point (either in Cloud Functions or elsewhere).